# delayed sync to main database when internet connection fail

Tags: database, data-synchronization

I have question about solution for this situation:

1, I want web application working on local web servers in few different locations.

2, Each location has local web server with copy of this application, which mainly tracks changes in warehouse and creates inserts in database.

3, All this applications should access same database on server via internet connection.

How to solve situation when internet connection is down and I want to continue work in application. 
After connection is restored, the application should pass all data changes to database server.

Is there any general solution for this situation?
Anybody knows web pages where one can find model of solution for this and another common programing/architecture problems?

Thank you all

Comment: Look into database replication.